# How to combine these 2 scripts and run multiple cron jobs for the same script to get different outputs?

Tags: bash, shell, cron, scheduled-tasks

First script runs once everyday at 11am and notifies that everything is working fine with "success" message.

```
if [ $Status == "200" ]; then
    echo "success"
else
    echo "error"
fi
```

Second script runs every 30 minutes and doesn't print anything unless there's an error. Basically it keeps on checking every 30 minutes if everything's working fine and notifies me of an error only if anything is down.

```
if [ $Status != "200" ]; then
    echo "error"
fi
```

Both the scripts have almost exactly the same code. But I'm using 2 different scripts because of different outputs I want at different times. So is there a way to combine both the scripts?

To be more clear, if possible, I want a single script that can send a success message everyday at 11am while also running every 30 minutes without sending that success message again and again and then only send error message if anything's down.

In crontab it's like this:

```
0 11 * * * /home/username/script1.sh
*/30 * * * * /home/username/script2.sh
```

Comment: how long does it take for the script to execute and generate the vaue in `$Status`? more than a minute?

Comment: @markp-fuso it's pretty quick. Less than a minute. But I've got the solution.

Comment: ok; looks like pmf covered what I was getting at, ie, if the script takes longer than a minute then you'll want to capture the script's start time right up front so it always matches `11:00` otherwise if you wait then `date` may return `11:01`, `11:02`, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your script run every 30 minutes. On success, check if it is 11am before outputting success.

```sh
if [ $Status == "200" ]; then
    if [ $(date +%H%M) == "1100" ]; then
        echo "success"
    fi
else
    echo "error"
fi
```

Note: This checks for exactly 11:00 am. If your script may take longer than 1 minute to reach this point, save the time somewhere at the beginning `time="$(date +%H%M)"` and check against it afterwards `if [ "$time" == "1100" ]`.

---

Alternatively, if you want to keep the actual time at which to behave differently outside the script, you can introduce a parameter that is set only (or in one way) on the 11 am run, but not (or in another way) on the other runs.

This requires you to still have multiple cron jobs, but with different parameters to the same script.

```sh
   0 11         * * * /home/username/script.sh yes
  30 11         * * * /home/username/script.sh no
*/30 0-10,12-23 * * * /home/username/script.sh no
```

Within the script you need to check the parameter provided.

```sh
printsuccess="$1"

if [ $Status == "200" ]; then
    if [ $printsuccess == "yes" ]; then
        echo "success"
    fi
else
    echo "error"
fi
```

Comment: How can I do this using flags? or how do I use flags here?

Comment: If by flags you mean providing [positional parameters](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Positional-Parameters) which can be tested in the script, then what I did with `yes` and `no` is exactly that. You reference it by using `$1` (or `${1}`). You can omit one alternative and just test for the existence of the other. You are free to rename it and e.g. let it start with a `-` dash sign. You can store it in a variable (see `printsuccess` above), and you can remove it from the list of positional parameters using `shift` to more easily access any others (if present).

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: The second solution (with yes and no) is not printing anything at all where it should be printing "success" message (works for error message though). Could you please test it once? Maybe test for this: `curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n" https://www.google.co.in`. Also I'm little confused about flags, if possible can you edit your answer and add them for better understanding? I'm new to this.

Comment: @Vishal **Where** does it not print anything? If run as a cron job you don't see the output in the same way as when run in a terminal window  - unless it is redirected, eg. into a file. Note that `curl -o /dev/null` will discard any output and `curl -s` will suppress any progress meter or error messages. Also, regarding "flags", I don't know what else to say besides what I have already said in my second solution and in my comment above, and what recently has essentially been [repeated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71342082/2158479) by others. Maybe show your desired usage with flags to clarify.

Comment: I've got it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Both the scripts have almost exactly the same code. But I'm using 2 different scripts because of different outputs I want at different times. So is there a way to combine both the scripts?

You should put all the complexity of getting the status code in a single script. Source this in wrapper scripts if neccesary: `. ~/get-code.bash`.

Instead of wrapper scripts, I would do:

```
0,30 0-10,12-23 * * * ~/get-code || echo error
  30 11         * * * ~/get-code || echo error
   0 11         * * * if ~/get-code; then echo success; else echo error; fi
```

To return success or failure base on `Status`, put this at the end of `~/get-code`:

```
if [ "$Status" = 200 ]; then
    exit 0
else
    exit 1
fi
```