# How do I combine these 2 scripts to run multiple cronjobs using flags?

Tags: bash, shell, cron, flags

I have 2 similar scripts. First one runs everyday once at a specific time and prints the "success" message at that time.

```
if [[ $status == 200 ]]; then
    echo "success"
else
    echo "error"
fi
```

Second script runs every 30 minutes and prints nothing unless there's an error.

```
if [[ $status != 200 ]]; then
    echo "error"
fi
```

I'm running both using cron jobs.

```
0 11 * * * /home/username/script1.sh
*/30 * * * * /home/username/script2.sh
```

I want to know how these 2 scripts can be combined preferably using **flags**. Basically I want a single script that can send a success message everyday at 9am while also running every 30 minutes without sending that success message again and again and then only sends error message if anything's down.

I did get solution for combining scripts: [How to combine these 2 scripts and run multiple cron jobs for the same script to get different outputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71226377/how-to-combine-these-2-scripts-and-run-multiple-cron-jobs-for-the-same-script-to/71226437?noredirect=1#comment126063774_71226437) but I'm confused on how should I do it with **flags** as I'm not much familiar with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a flag `--error-only` and check for this in the script.

```
if [[ $status == 200 ]]; then
    if [[ "$1" != "--error-only" ]]; then
        echo "success"
    fi
else
    echo "error"
fi
```

Then modify the crontab to pass that flag except for one of the runs.

```
0 11 * * * /home/username/script1.sh
*/30 0-10,12-23 * * * /home/username/script1.sh --error-only
30 11 * * * /home/username/script1.sh --error-only
```